# Terminal Services License Server will only issue temporary licenses

Tags: windows, terminal-server, licensing

I have a Windows 2003 machine as a license server and two Windows 2000 servers running Terminal Services. For some reason I can't fathom, the license server will only issue temporary licenses.

If I run licmgr.exe, I get the following information:

```
Product                                                                               Type      Total     Available Issued
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- --------- --------- --------- ---------
Existing Windows 2000 Server - Terminal Services CAL Token (per device)               Built-in  Unlimited Unlimited 0
Temporary Licenses for Windows 2000 Server - Terminal Services CAL Token (per device) Temporary -         -         14
Windows 2000 server - terminal services cal token (per device)                        Open      10        0         0
```

I've worked around this problem on the clients (mostly Wyse Winterms, and the occasional PC) by regularly clearing the license store with either [SNMP](http://pastebin.com/f492ed556) or a remote script.

Any ideas how to fix the underlying problem though, or what may be causing it?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you haven't activated your license server. It will only issue temporary licenses valid for 120 days.

This KB explains the activation process. [KB325869](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/325869)

Answer (score 0):

If your TS server is unable to locate the license server try hard coding the license server in the registry. You'll need to Google for the correct key, as I don't recall where it is and I'm just about to head home.

Answer (score 0):

Check Microsoft KB 834651.  The issue it's reporting is supposedly fixed in SP1 and later, but I've seen this issue over and over again.  If the reg entry it wants you to modify doesn't exist then create it as a DWORD and set it to per user or per device.

http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=834651